# Create data specific to list items in c#

Tags: c#, list

I'm working on a small application that utilities a list of items, each item has a set of data associated with it. I'm very much a beginner, so I'm not sure how to do this efficiently.

For example, my list contains the following:

```
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
Item 4
```

Each item would then have 6 or so associated pieces of data, i.e.

```
Item 1
  Material 1
  Material 2
  Material 3
```

etc. Currently my GUI contains the list of Items and a secondary list that would display the Materials required for the item upon selected an item from the primary list. At first I thought I could achieve that by using an if statement to populate based off the selected item, however the item list contains quite a few items and this seems terribly inefficient. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: If your lists can be quite large in terms of items, and you require it to be efficiently as possible I would recommend using a hashed set. View : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on your needed data structure; Either you need a class so that each item can have a set of properties of different type (string, int, or even list...). Either you can simply consider an item being a list of text properties , and your list of items will be a list of lists.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to this. Note the hashed set.

```
public class ShopMaterial
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class ShopItem 
{
    public string ShopItemName { get; set; }
    public HashSet<ShopMaterial> ShopMaterialList { get; set; }
}
```

Then later, you can get the material by doing the following, with the help of Linq.

```
ShopItem si = new ShopItem();
si.ShopMaterialList.Add(new ShopMaterial() { Id = 1, Name = "Item 1" });
si.ShopMaterialList.Add(new ShopMaterial() { Id = 1, Name = "Item 2" });
si.ShopMaterialList.Add(new ShopMaterial() { Id = 1, Name = "Item 3" });

si.ShopMaterialList.Where(item => item.Name == "Item 1").First();
```